# How do I integrate a module?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

UPDATE: I changed my model a bit, but it still do not works. I get the following error message: **ActionController::RoutingError (undefined local variable or method `stop_words_finder' for #< Class:0x007facb57f6908 >)**

**models/pool.rb**

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base

    include StopWords

    attr_accessible :fragment

  def self.delete_stop_words(data)
    words = data.scan(/\w+/)
    stop_words = stop_words_finder
    key_words = words.select { |word| !stop_words.include?(word) }

    pool_frag = Pool.create :fragment => key_words.join(' ')
  end
end
```

**lib/stop_words.rb**

```
module StopWords
      def stop_words_finder
            %w{house}
      end
end
```

**controllers/tweets_controller.rb**

```
class TweetsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @tweets = Pool.all

    respond_with(@tweets)
  end
end
```

Comment: Looks like you want a fulltext search engine - don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Top tip: instead of saying something "doesn't work", describe what happened and how it differed from what you expected.

Comment: Looks like you're accessing this through a controller... have you restarted the application after changes made in the `lib` directory?

Comment: I restarted the rails server, but the Error is the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
stop_words = :stop_words_finder
```

assigns the symbol `:stop_words_finder` to `stop_words`. What you want to do is call the `stop_words_finder` method that you included from `Stopwords`, which will return the array. In this case, all you have to do is remove the colon.

```
stop_words = stop_words_finder
```

Comment: This is a bit of guess though, since you didn't include any error message in your question. That would help determine what's going wrong.

Comment: If I remove the colon, I get the following error message: undefined local variable or method `stop_words_finder'

Comment: Frederick Cheung pointed out the bigger problem: you're not including `Stopwords` in the correct class. If you do that my answer will apply.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your model to make stop_words_finder available to Pool instances:

```
include StopWords
```

Pool.new.stop_words_finder will work

To make stop_words_finder available to the Pool class, use extend:

```
extend StopWords
```

Pool.stop_words_finder will work.

Also, why on earth are you creating an instance of Pool inside the Pool class definition?

Answer (score 0):

As it stands you're including the module into your ApplicationController class. This has absolutely no effect on the `Pool` class. In addition creating instances of the `Pool` class inside its definition is rather unorthodox - do you really want to create a new row in your database everytime the code to your app is loaded? I would refactor things along these lines

```
class Pool < ActiveRecord::Base
  class << self
    include StopWords

    def create_from_data(data)
      words = data.scan(/\w+/)
      stop_words = stop_words_finder
      key_words = words.select { |word| !stop_words.include?(word) }

      pool = Pool.create :pooltext => key_words.join(' ')
    end
  end
end
```

You'd then call `Pool.create_from_data %q{Ich gehe heute schwimmen. Und du?}` when you want to create it.

Comment: I did what you say. But now I have this Error: undefined local variable or method `stop_words_finder' for #<Class:0x007fb20b1217d0>

Comment: I can't load the module StopWords.

Comment: that sounds like you've got the `include StopWords` line in the wrong place